# I can't get Ubuntu to work on my laptop

Tags: system-installation

When I insert my disk and restart my laptop, it goes to the start up screen and says that my disk is corrupted or there is data missing and then requires that I start up with windows 7.I have tried the 32 bit and 64 bit and the 32 bit is corrupted and 64 bit wont play on my laptop. Please help me.

Comment: It is possible that your DVD did not burn correctly. You could try to boot the same dvd on another computer or try to use a live USB instead.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the iso [check the md5sum for correctness](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto). If it isn't correct, there's no needs to spoil a disk. When burning, make sure to have the disk checked after burning - or better yet [use an usb stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick).